# Message format for deeplink with react-native-push-notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, react-navigation, react-native-push-notification, react-native-deep-linking

I am using [react-native-push-notification library](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) to send local notifications from my ios app. I have setup deeplink using [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/). I have also managed the local push notification to deeplink into specific app screen on click. But this requires me to set the in the `message` property. This means the resulting lo shows the URL in its display. This is ugly and I would like to hide the URL. Any pointers?

Here is how i schedule local notification

```
        PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        title: "main title",
        subtitle: "fake sub title",
        message: "example://detail/one",
        bigText: "My big text that will be shown when expanded",
        date: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000),
        allowWhileIdle: false,
        });
```

Here is my onNotification code

```
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);

    let isClicked = notification.data.userInteraction === 1
    if (isClicked) {
      Linking.openURL(notification.message)
    }

    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  },
```

Now this results in the `example://detail/one` url being displayed in notification. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution to the above issue. But I switched to [Notifee](https://notifee.app) for local push notifications. And it just worked! So much easier to install and very minimal configuration needed. Was just an intuitive I expected the notification library to be.